# How to stop spam in PHPBB3?

Tags: spam-prevention, phpbb3

I'm getting awful lot of spam to my forums where only registered users can post and captcha is in use. What could we best solution to stop spammers registering to my forums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had some success by making the image a background of a DIV (instead of using an IMG element). Most spam bots ignore background CSS styles.

If you want to make life a little bit harder for the spammers, leave the IMG in, use an different image in there, and set it to `display: none;`. The bot will have a hard time to figure out that the IMG isn't visible.

Answer (score 1):

FUDForum is somewhat better for me. It has been pretty much hands free and I have installed a few. So far no spam no bots.

The reason I believe fudforum has survived spam bot challenge is because it uses ASCII text for captcha. You could try to reuse it in other forums.